# SwiftUI ScrollView Scroll to Relative Position

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview, horizontalscrollview, scrollviewreader

I have a big horizontal view that doesn't fit on screen, so I put it into a horizontal `ScrollView`.
If 0 would represent scrolled to the left completely and 1 to the right completely - How can I e.g. scroll to a relative position of 0.8?

Since I cannot attach an id to a child element `ScrollViewReader` doesn't seem to work.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            Text("Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on.")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can solve this in pure-SwiftUI by using a `ZStack` with invisible background views:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { reader in
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                ZStack {
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                            Spacer().id(i)
                        }
                    }
                    Text("Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on.")
                }
            }
            Button("Go to 0.8") {
                withAnimation {
                    reader.scrollTo(80)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

With [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect), used to "Introspect underlying UIKit components from SwiftUI", we can achieve this.

Here is how it's done, complete with a `Slider` to demonstrate it working:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var relativePosition: CGFloat = 0.5
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                Text("Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on. Example for a long view without individual elements that you could use id on.")
            }
            .introspectScrollView { scrollView in
                let width = scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.width
                scrollView.contentOffset.x = relativePosition * width
            }
            
            let _ = relativePosition  // Needed to update view
            
            Slider(value: $relativePosition, in: 0 ... 1)
        }
    }
}
```